# Center of gravity for an object

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

How can I reset or place the center of gravity for an active ridged body object? I am having an issue where the center of gravity for an object is placed far too high for accurate physics.

Answer (score 6):

The center of gravity is placed at the object origin. To put move the object origin, press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

*Center of Mass* will put the origin (center of gravity) at the center of mass, assuming a uniform density.

*3D cursor* will put the origin at the 3D cursor, allowing for more customized setups.

Comment: But how to do it on an animated object avoiding ruining of all animations?

Comment: @Monkok That's a very good question. Care to ask it that in a new post (and link to this one if it helps provide context)? Comments aren't really suitable for extended answers

Comment: here is my [question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/72172/18777)