# How to change animated object's origin without ruining animation?

Tags: animation, scripting, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation, coordinates

For example: I have a character and a spoon which he is holding and moving thanks to child of constrain. My character releases the spoon a little bit above a plate. So I came up with idea to use rigid body on both to get realistic spoon falling to the plate animation (yes, I could animate it myself, but that seams to be more of a time wasting). But **here is the problem**: my spoon's origin was at its center for the whole time obviously, and now to get a correct rigid body simulation I need to move the origin, but that will ruin all of the animation!

So I thought that to keep the animation I need to add to each axis of keyframed movement for the spoon after changing its origin difference between corresponding locations of both origins. Hope I managed to describe it clear enough.

Though, the idea is very simple I don't know how to realise it, so that it would do the thing throughout the whole timeline, Somehow via scripting maybe? It could be some addon for auto "solving" new origins animations.

P.S. first I'd bake action for the child of I guess and then do all of the above.

Comment: Have you tried duplicating the spoon, and using the second spoon for the rigid body simulation, and toggling the visibility of the spoons to make the transition seamless?

Comment: No, i know I could do that but it's just not what I want, considering that the answer to my question could help someone in similar situation