# Center of gravity multiple objects overlapping

Tags: objects

I wish to know if my figure is going to fall over if I print it (not talking about printing, but the final result after removing printing support). I used lots of different objects that partially overlap. Of course Blender should not use that overlapping volume twice.
Is there a way to show the center of gravity? Then I can see if that is above the supporting parts (legs and crutches in this case).
[image]

[image]

I have considered exporting it as stl and see in CURA where the center of gravity is, but that's a hassle to do each time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Visually I'd  it I'd say it would fall over.

Comment: As it is now yes, but I will change it until it no longer will fall. But I want to change it as little as possible and therefore would like to know where the centre of gravity is.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26845/center-of-gravity-for-an-object

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: I don't do 3D printing, but I could imagine it also depends on how thick you make the outisde and if you leave it hollow or fill it with a pattern or fully. So these are things that are hard to consider from the plain mesh. Maybe you could remesh the object or add everything together with a Boolean modifier, apply those changes (to a duplicate object of course) and then _Set Origin to Center of Mass_, either "Surface" if you're going for a hollow print, or "Volume" if it's a full solid print. Everything inbetween... I don't know.